# How to spread Entities over different modules in Spring-data-jpa and eclipselink?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I am currently developing an application with a core module and different "extension" modules. The core module includes the JPA configuration based on a Spring configuration class as well as some "basic" entities and their repositories which shall be used in the "extension" modules. The extension modules contain additional Entity classes and JPARepositories. When starting the JUnit Test for an extension module I encounter the following error:

```
No [ManagedType] was found for the key class [a.b.c.data.Config] in 
the Metamodel - please verify that the [Managed] class was referenced
in persistence.xml using a specific <class>a.b.c.data.Config</class>
property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
element.
```

To accomplish this I tried three different approaches:

- Created one LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with the name coreEntityManager with setPackagesToScan including the core and the extension package which contain the @Entity classes and the @EnableJpaRepositories pointing to the core repository package and the spring config of the extension having the @EnableJpaRepositories pointing to the extension repository package
- Created an additional LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean in the spring config for the extension with its own JPaRepository Annotation and with setPackagesToScan pointing only to the extension package containing the @Entity classes. The coreEntityManager in this case points only to the package in the core module containing the @Entity classes.
- Created one LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with the name coreEntityManager with setPackagesToScan including the core and the extension package which contain the @Entity classes and the @EnableJpaRepositories pointing to the core and the extension repo packages

With the first two approaches the already mentioned error shows up while with the third approach there's the config repository not found:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'a.b.c.ext.repositories.ConfigRepository' available
```

Code for approach 1:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"a.b.c.core.services"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"a.b.c.core.repositories"}, entityManagerFactoryRef = "coreEntityManager")
public class CoreJPAConfig {
...
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean coreEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        JpaDialect jpaDialect = new EclipseLinkJpaDialect();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(getJpaProperties());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("a.core");
        em.setPackagesToScan("a.b.c.core.data",
                "a.b.c.ext.data");
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return em;
    }
...
}

Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "a.b.c.config.services"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"a.b.c.ext.repositories"}, entityManagerFactoryRef = "coreEntityManager")
public class JobSpringConfig {
...
}
```

code for approach 2:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"a.b.c.core.services"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"a.b.c.core.repositories"}, entityManagerFactoryRef = "coreEntityManager")
public class CoreJPAConfig {
...
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean coreEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        JpaDialect jpaDialect = new EclipseLinkJpaDialect();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(getJpaProperties());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("a.core");
        em.setPackagesToScan("a.b.c.core.data");
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return em;
    }
...
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"a.b.c.config.services"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"a.b.c.ext.repositories"}, entityManagerFactoryRef = "jobEntityManager")
public class JobSpringConfig {
...
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean jobEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        JpaDialect jpaDialect = new EclipseLinkJpaDialect();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(getJpaProperties());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("a.config");
        em.setPackagesToScan("a.b.c.ext.data");
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return em;
    }
```

code for approach 3:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"a.b.c.core.services"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"a.b.c.core.repositories",
        "a.b.c.ext.repositories"}, entityManagerFactoryRef = "coreEntityManager")
public class CoreJPAConfig {
...
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean coreEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        JpaDialect jpaDialect = new EclipseLinkJpaDialect();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(getJpaProperties());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("a.core");
        em.setPackagesToScan("a.b.c.core.data",
                "a.b.c.ext.data");
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return em;
    }
...
```

What I want to achieve at the end is to have a kind of "Lego" building blocks where the modules and their configuration can simply be added as a dependency and the corresponding configuration entities (and their tables) are added to the persistency unit without the need of further tweaking.

Anyone able to help me?

kind regards

defect

Comment: This does not exactly answer your question, but I'd seriously consider a design in which the core module and each of the extension modules is a separate [bounded context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html), with facades for inter-module communication

Comment: @crizzis: Thanks for your valuable comment. Still I want to have the setup so that in the core are the common entities which can be used for most of the extension modules. The entities in there are Property, History and HistoryRecord. Let's say I have a SOAP service module which implements a given contract. The service should have a ServiceConfig having a list of property and history entities. Each History Entity shall have 0 or more detailed "log" records. 
in case there is now an additional module for scheduled jobs this module could use the same Property, History and HistoryRecord entities

Comment: Relying on package scanning seems like it would be a problem with classes you want outside the persistence unit. You can list the classes you want and any makeshift mappings you may need with a separate ORM.xml for each configuration.  EclipseLink allows specifying a eclipselink-orm.xml file that you could use to merge over a core orm.xml file, to specify additional classes and mappings - see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/schema.htm .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I wasn't able to see the wood for the trees... I missed the @Entity annotation in one of the extension entities... DUH! *facepalm*

Thanks to everyone reading my question and trying to help! Shame on me!

Comment: So which of your approach was worked? I'm facing the same issue with you :')